# Adding Arraylist to custom object not updating values in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In the below android activity, trying to display data in a view pager and it is working as expected.

But in loadItemsForSuppliers method, when i am adding SupplierAndItemList object to it's arraylist, value returned from getInventoriesByItemDetails method is not updating properly rather takes last value always.

Can some body assist me what's wrong here ?

```
     public class ScreenSlidePagerActivity extends BaseActivity {
                private ViewPager mPager;
                private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
                private Dealer dealerObject;
                private ArrayList<ItemDetail> itemDetails;
                private List<Dealer> supplierList;
                private ArrayList<SupplierAndItemList> supplierAndItemLists = new ArrayList<>();


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);
                dealerObject = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(UiConstants.DEALER_OBJECT);
                itemDetails = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("itemDetails");
                supplierList = dealerObject.getParentSalesPoints(this,dealerObject.getServerId());

                loadItemsForSuppliers();

                mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),supplierAndItemLists);
                mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
            }

            private void loadItemsForSuppliers() {
                 for (Dealer dealer : supplierList) {
                     ArrayList<ItemDetail> inventories = new ArrayList<>();

                     SupplierAndItemList supplierAndItem = new SupplierAndItemList();
                     supplierAndItem.setDealerName(dealer.getDealerName());
                     supplierAndItem.setSelectedItemList(getInventoriesByItemDetails(dealer, inventories));
                  supplierAndItemLists.add(supplierAndItem);

                 }
            }

            private ArrayList<ItemDetail> getInventoriesByItemDetails(Dealer dealer, ArrayList<ItemDetail> inventories) {

                    for (ItemDetail id : itemDetails) {
                        DealerInventory dealerInventory = new DealerInventory();
                        dealerInventory = dealerInventory.getLastModifiedInventory(this, id.getItemId(), dealer.getId());
                        if (dealerInventory != null) {
                            if (dealerInventory.getQuantity() >= 0) {
                                id.setParentSalesPointLastStock(String.valueOf(dealerInventory.getQuantity()));
                                id.setParentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate(dealerInventory.getStockTakingDate());
                            }
                        } else {
                            id.setParentSalesPointLastStock(UiConstants.NA);
                            id.setParentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate(UiConstants.NA);
                        }
                        inventories.add(id);
                    }
                    return inventories;
                }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final ArrayList<SupplierAndItemList> supplierAndItemList;
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<SupplierAndItemList> supplierAndItemList) {
            super(fm);
            this.supplierAndItemList = supplierAndItemList;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            SupplierAndItemList supplierAndItems = supplierAndItemList.get(position);
            ScreenSlidePageFragment f = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("supplierAndItems",supplierAndItems.getSelectedItemList());
            bundle.putString("supplierName",supplierAndItems.getDealerName());
            f.setArguments(bundle);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return supplierAndItemList.size();
        }
    }
  }
```

SupplierAndItemList class

```
public class SupplierAndItemList implements Parcelable {
    public String dealerName;
    public ArrayList<ItemDetail> selectedItemList;

    public SupplierAndItemList() {
        selectedItemList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getDealerName() {
        return dealerName;
    }

    public void setDealerName(String dealerName) {
        this.dealerName = dealerName;
    }

    public ArrayList<ItemDetail> getSelectedItemList() {
        return selectedItemList;
    }

    public void setSelectedItemList(ArrayList<ItemDetail> itemList) {
        this.selectedItemList = itemList;
    }

    protected SupplierAndItemList(Parcel in) {
        dealerName = in.readString();
        selectedItemList = in.readArrayList(ItemDetail.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(dealerName);
        dest.writeList(selectedItemList);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SupplierAndItemList> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SupplierAndItemList>() {
        @Override
        public SupplierAndItemList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SupplierAndItemList(in);
        }

        @Override
        public SupplierAndItemList[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SupplierAndItemList[size];
        }
    };
}
```

ItemDetail class

```
public class ItemDetail implements Parcelable {

    public int itemId;
    public String itemName;

    public String salesPointLastStock;
    public String salesPointLastStockTakingDate;
    public String parentSalesPointLastStock;
    public String parentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate;

    public IDStockInput idStockInput;
    public IDReturnInput idReturnInput;
    public IDOrderInput idOrderInput;

    public boolean isSelected;

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setIsSelected(boolean isUpdated) {
        this.isSelected = isUpdated;
    }

    public String getParentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate() {
        return parentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate;
    }

    public void setParentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate(String parentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate) {
        this.parentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate = parentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate;
    }

    public String getParentSalesPointLastStock() {
        return parentSalesPointLastStock;
    }

    public void setParentSalesPointLastStock(String parentSalesPointLastStock) {
        this.parentSalesPointLastStock = parentSalesPointLastStock;
    }

    @NonNull
    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(int itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getSalesPointLastStock() {
        return salesPointLastStock;
    }

    public void setSalesPointLastStock(String salesPointLastStock) {
        this.salesPointLastStock = salesPointLastStock;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getSalesPointLastStockTakingDate() {
        return salesPointLastStockTakingDate;
    }

    public void setSalesPointLastStockTakingDate(String salesPointLastStockTakingDate) {
        this.salesPointLastStockTakingDate = salesPointLastStockTakingDate;
    }

    public IDStockInput getIdStockInput() {
        return idStockInput;
    }

    public void setIdStockInput(IDStockInput idStockInput) {
        this.idStockInput = idStockInput;
    }

    public IDReturnInput getIdReturnInput() {
        return idReturnInput;
    }

    public void setIdReturnInput(IDReturnInput idReturnInput) {
        this.idReturnInput = idReturnInput;
    }

    public IDOrderInput getIdOrderInput() {
        return idOrderInput;
    }

    public void setIdOrderInput(IDOrderInput idOrderInput) {
        this.idOrderInput = idOrderInput;
    }

    public ItemDetail() {
        idStockInput = new IDStockInput();
        idReturnInput = new IDReturnInput();
        idOrderInput = new IDOrderInput();
    }

    protected ItemDetail(Parcel in) {
        itemId = in.readInt();
        itemName = in.readString();
        salesPointLastStock = in.readString();
        salesPointLastStockTakingDate = in.readString();
        parentSalesPointLastStock = in.readString();
        parentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate = in.readString();
        isSelected =in.readInt()==1;
        idStockInput = (IDStockInput) in.readValue(IDStockInput.class.getClassLoader());
        idReturnInput = (IDReturnInput) in.readValue(IDReturnInput.class.getClassLoader());
        idOrderInput = (IDOrderInput) in.readValue(IDOrderInput.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(itemId);
        dest.writeString(itemName);
        dest.writeString(salesPointLastStock);
        dest.writeString(salesPointLastStockTakingDate);
        dest.writeString(parentSalesPointLastStock);
        dest.writeString(parentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate);
        dest.writeInt(isSelected ? 1 : 0);
        dest.writeValue(idStockInput);
        dest.writeValue(idReturnInput);
        dest.writeValue(idOrderInput);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ItemDetail> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ItemDetail>() {
        @Override
        public ItemDetail createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ItemDetail(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ItemDetail[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ItemDetail[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have go through your method I have found some assigning value issue

```
private void loadItemsForSuppliers() {
                 for (Dealer dealer : supplierList) {
                     ArrayList<ItemDetail> inventories = new ArrayList<>();

                     SupplierAndItemList supplierAndItem = new SupplierAndItemList();
                     supplierAndItem.setDealerName(dealer.getDealerName());
                     supplierAndItem.setSelectedItemList(getInventoriesByItemDetails(dealer, inventories));
                  supplierAndItemLists.add(supplierAndItem);

                 }
            }

            private ArrayList<ItemDetail> getInventoriesByItemDetails(Dealer dealer, ArrayList<ItemDetail> inventories) {

                    for (ItemDetail id : itemDetails) {
                        DealerInventory dealerInventory = new DealerInventory();
                        dealerInventory = dealerInventory.getLastModifiedInventory(this, id.getItemId(), dealer.getId());
                        if (dealerInventory != null) {
                            if (dealerInventory.getQuantity() >= 0) {
                                id.setParentSalesPointLastStock(String.valueOf(dealerInventory.getQuantity()));
                                id.setParentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate(dealerInventory.getStockTakingDate());
                            }
                        } else {
                            id.setParentSalesPointLastStock(UiConstants.NA);
                            id.setParentSalesPointLastStockTakingDate(UiConstants.NA);
                        }
                    inventories.add(id); // do this
                    }
                    return inventories; // you are not assigning value  anywhere;
                }
```

You are not assigning value to the `inventories` in `getInventoriesByItemDetails`. I think you should add item through `inventories.add(id);`
Check it , Hope this help

Comment: Had missed that line while posting query. It is not causing the issue, returned value of getInventoriesByItemDetails will have proper arraylist. After setting it to  SupplierAndItemList, also holds correct value. But when SupplierAndItemList is inserted to ArrayList<SupplierAndItemList> by calling supplierAndItemLists.add(supplierAndItem) , gives last value in ArrayList<ItemDetails>

Comment: @user3752389, I think you should clear `supplierAndItemLists` on starting of  `loadItemsForSuppliers()`

Comment: As we are adding items after initialisation, and never using same array list no need to clear it. Still tried it, but didn't helped

Answer (score -1):

Set

```
mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

Comment: This didn't helped